# How to add icon inside EditText view in Android ?

Tags: android

I want to add a "search" icon to appear inside an `EditText` in the left edge? such as search box in Facebook Android app?

Answer (score 485, accepted):

Use the [`android:drawableLeft`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) property on the EditText.

```
<EditText
    ...     
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

Comment: sorry for unclear question , i want to add a button , so wheni click on it , it do some action

Comment: This was just the solution I expected, given the search heading.

Comment: Also, adjust the padding using the `drawablePadding` property.

Comment: so what should be the size of that drawable icon and in which folder should i place it?

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani : Usually the edittext and drawables should be 32dp according to the android design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Comment: @marcosbeirigo This didn't work for me. its filling the whole edit text in a weird way.

Comment: use drawableStart for RTL support

Answer (score 35):

You can set drawableLeft in the XML as suggested by [marcos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281749/how-to-add-icon-inside-edittext-view-in-android/4281770#4281770), but you might also want to set it programmatically - for example in response to an event. To do this use the method **[setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrincisBounds(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)**:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

// Set drawables for left, top, right, and bottom - send 0 for nothing
editTxt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.myDrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This sets background to the EditText, not the icon/image at the "Left Edge" which is clearly mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Paresh - which is why I deleted the answer. I have now edited to include a programmatic solution in addition to the original XML solution.

Comment: how to programatically hide the icon ? when edit box is clicked  ?

Comment: @Hunt - Just set the coumound drawable to `null` when the view is clicked.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to use Android's default drawable, you can use `@android:drawable/ic_menu_search` like this:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:hint="Search product.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use :

```
<EditText
    ..     
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative layout and set the button the be align left of the edit text view, and set the left padding of your text view to the size of your button.  I can't think of a good way to do it without hard coding the padding :/

You can also use [apk tool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to sorta unzip the facebook apk and take a look at its layout files.

Comment: I would like to mention that decompilation is against the law in many countries  for example in whole European Union so please be carefull :)

Answer (score 0):

```
` <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:hint=" Search" />`
```