# Clickable Button (or any View) inside EditText in android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I want to have a Button or a clickable View in my EditText so that I can perform some action on click of it. I was able to put a drawable inside my EditText thanks to [Marcosbeirigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181915/marcosbeirigo) for [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281770/840669) But, now I want to make it clickable so that I can perform some action on it. I know this is possible as HTC uses buttons inside EditText in their stock sms app as shown in the following image-

[image: Send button in EditText]

In my case, the button will be positioned anywhere, can be in the center also. But the main thing is how can I put a button in EditText?

Comment: You can make a [portion clickable](http://adilatwork.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-how-to-make-only-part-of.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout. The Send and Attach buttons are simple Android Buttons and the 32/160 is a TextView. Put the buttons and the textview on the EditText object, play with the layout arrangments and set some right padding to the EditText object so that the text inside it won't go under the buttons.

You don't need any drawable and listening to the click event of the android buttons is not a question anymore.
Its absolutely correct

Answer (score 7):

Use this , It worked for me -

```
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/id_search_EditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:hint="Enter your feelings and connect" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/id_search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/id_search_EditText"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/id_search_EditText"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/id_search_EditText"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you try to search set click event for compound drawable. You can find some solutions here

[handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

there is no button inside editText It's just an editText with white background so you don't see it's margins and a simple layout arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution is to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) that allow you to put also Views in overlay to others. Other Layout wont allow you to do such things.

Also I found this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html maybe it can helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: output]

Use this this code may work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/REFReLayTellFriend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/editext_rounded"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_content_filter_list"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```