# Adding icons in EditText for messaging purpose like whatsapp or msn

Tags: android

I have researched on Google how to insert icons in EditText. However, most of it is talking about something like: [How to add icon inside EditText view in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281749/how-to-add-icon-inside-edittext-view-in-android).
That is adding a static icons.
However, what I like is adding icons between the text like typing message in MSN or Whatsapp.  First of all, there is a button near the EditText. When clicked, show a dialog that can choose any icons.  After choosing the icons, it will append after the text.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: use [ImageSpan](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Ftext%2Fstyle%2FImageSpan.html&ei=juIDUJeeOcnirAeQ1bSYBg&usg=AFQjCNEM0s0tlDOHb9PawrF_d4S3awgoLw&sig2=IeMdjfqKco5JYpl5npW4lw) for adding images between text in textView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this ![image: this] so [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) is what you want.And [Introduction to Spans](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177) is complete tutorial how to use Spans